# How to display results from multiple mysql tables orderd by a date column in one loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MYSQL to display an **overview** for the latest user activities.
[image: 1]

I have like five activities, but lets say we just have two activities (posts and comments), so basically using MYSQL I have to get results from two tables ordered by a date column (all the activities tables have a date column), then using PHP I need to loop through those results and for each result type (either a post or a comment) I need to handle it differently (posts and comments have different html).

The first thing that was on my mind is the **MYSQL UNION ALL Operator** but w3schools says

> each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order

And my posts and comments tables don't have the same number of columns or data types, also I don't know how to handle each result type differently.

I am lost right know, if you could help me in any way that would be great, Thank you.

### Extra

Here is an example of posts and comments tables

```
-- Comments table  
id|user_id|post_id|c_date|comment

-- Posts table
id|user_id|p_date|title|content
```

### Update1

I am not trying to join rows, I want to display each row as it's own, not joined it with another row.

Comment: use join operation

Comment: Can you tell us more about the tables structure? Whats `id` and whats `uid` ? Are they linked to oneanother?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam join is for joining rows together, I am not trying to join rows, I want to display each row as it's own, not joined it with another row.

Comment: since posts and comments have different html, a php solution would worth a try.

Comment: @paskl `id` is just an auto increment column for the table, `uid` is the user `id` nothing is linked with each other

Comment: So how do you know if a user has made a comment in some `post` ?

Comment: I forgot to add a `post_id` column, but that's not important here, I am trying to display results from different tables all ordered by a date column, that's what imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution for this problem, here is the MYSQL syntax

```
SELECT c_date AS date, comment AS content, '' AS title, 'comment' AS type FROM comments
UNION ALL 
SELECT p_date AS date, content, title, 'post' AS type FROM posts
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The trick here is to use **'AS'** in MYSQL to give the columns the same name (`c_date AS date`) (`comment AS content`), and to match them (`'' AS title`), and also use them as variable for holding the **'type'** (`'comment' AS type`)

And using php I looped through the results and used **'type'** to handle each result type differently

```
$results = $connection->query($mysql_syntax);
if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['type'] == 'comment'){
            COMMENT HTML CODE HERE
        }elseif($row['type'] == 'post'){
            POST HTML CODE HERE
        }
    }
}
```

I wouldn't fond this solution if it wasn't for **@Kaushal Shah** answer, also I want to thank **@dtkahl** for his answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no "elegant" way to do this in one single query. I recommend the following:

1. write and execute a query for each table
2. Map results to php array and add a `type` (comment/post/...) field to each result row
3. sort the array by date (e.g. with [usort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php))

With the `type` on each result row, you can decide how to render it in your loop (use different html).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column 1, column 2, '' AS 'column 3' FROM table a
UNION  
SELECT column 1, column 2, column 3 FROM table b
```

You can use UNION in the following way if you know the structure of the tables before hand

Comment: But how to handle each result type differently?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query that fetches content from both tables into one row. The query should read something like this:

```
SELECT c_date, p_date, comment, title, content FROM Comments, Posts WHERE Comments.u_id = 'user' AND Posts.u_id = 'user'
```

Experiment with LIMIT and ORDER BY clauses and also remember to use table aliases and/or fully qualified column names.

Comment: But how to handle each result type differently?

Comment: Use the column names. The last comment by the user is in the 'comment' and the time is in 'c_date', the last post by the user is in 'title' and 'content' and its time is in 'p_date', and so on. That is why I said aliases might be important.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example to see? if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: I could, but I want to be sure of my assumption that you are looking to find out just the most recent (ONE) of each type of activity of the user. i.e The last comment, the last post e.t.c and not a list of the most recent comments and most recent posts

Comment: I am looking for a list of the most recent comments and posts

Comment: If thats the case, I can't think of one query that would quite cut it. dtkahl's answer would suit this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create another table called "useractivities" or smth. like that, and structure it like this:

- ID
- userID
- action (post, answer, registered, login, ....)
- actionID (this links to the id in the specific table)
- timestamp

Simply generate an entry in this table everytime something happens that you want recorded.

This way, you would only need to query this one table to get the latest user activities of a selected user, or you would be able to get all last activities on your page.

Comment: I though about that at first but I didn't like it, each time something happens (post, comment, review, ...) I need to post it to that table, also when the user deletes (post, comment, review, ...) I need to deleted from that table too, also each table (post, comment, review, ...) have some imported columns that I need like the content, so I'll have to fetch that from each table (post, comment, review, ...) in every results from the "useractivities" table.

Comment: Then for example why dont you create a universal table for any entities that are user generated? It would basically be the same, except you could also create helper tables to store additional data.
Also you could create an query that is filled by the variables in your useractivities table. SELECT * from $action WHERE ID = $actionID, $actionID2, ...

Comment: This would generate n + 1 db queries, n being the number of action tables you have in total.
if you only have post, comment, this would result in 3 DB queries in total to display this page.